# Force JSF partial rerender from CDI Conntext

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

Hy there:

I have two seperate JSF modules, linked via CDI @Observes.

- Module F: fires an Event
- Module O: @Observes Event

that works fine.

Now: When a user fires an event in Module F, I want to update a client component in Module O.
Is that somehow possible? can I manipulate the view of Module O, even though the JSF cycle has been entered from Module F?

**edit:**
I'm looking for a passive way supported by the server.
BalusC gave a hint of push/pull.
But a socket-like connection is not possible currently. Is there another way? Maybe similar to Omnifaces Ajax#update() - but without the jsf cycle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The missing keyword is "push" or perhaps "poll".

Comment: @BalusC naiv question: so you would say, there's no other way than (constantly) client side pull or server side push depending on a socket-like connection? Was I was looking for, was a passive server push. (edited post)